# Htaccess Image redirect to specific resize directory

Tags: .htaccess

Hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction as htaccess is driving me crazy at the moment.

What i am trying to achieve is an automatic redirect for certain images

Currently I use jquery to replace the image src.
The reason for this is the new resized images are in a different directory.

The problem with this method is every time we refresh we have to wait for the dom to fully load.
And I see this is possible with `htaccess`.

`Redirect /my-domain.com/images/image1.png /my-domain.com/images/resized/image1.png`

Currently this works, but for over 100 images I really need to find a dynamic solution for this

I tried the following which obviously failed.

`RewriteRule ^/my-domain.com/images/(.*) /my-domain.com/images/resized/(.*) [R=301,L]`

the resized directory has several directory's so the rule needs to apply to all child directories.
Although it's not a big problem to list all the directories as long as I don't list all images.

hopefully I am missing something simple here, also I wanted to make sure the redirect will not effect SEO?

maybe there is an alternative solution with htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a messy way to handle images - across multiple folders - but, if that's how you want to manage it, fair enough.

From the above, I understand that:

- There are some images within the `/images/resized/` folder
- There are also some images within subfolders of the same
- You want to be able to call a URL within the `/images/` folder and have it transcribed to the `/images/resize/` folder (with the same end)

In the webroot's .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/resized/
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)$ /images/resized/$1
```

Tested OK with this [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

"*I wanted to make sure the redirect will not effect SEO?*"
Filenames are not as important for SEO as alt tags and titles. There should be no change to the SEO stance of your site as a result of this change.